# WPF Binding without path with converter, update

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a binding without path using a converter. This is because the converter will use many properties of the object to build the text for the tooltip. But when one property changes (INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented and OnPropertyChanged raised), this binding without path does not get updated. I guess because it does not bind to a specific property.

How to tell that it has to update?

---

I try to be more specific:

The bar object has a 'Start' property. When I change this the bar moves in time because the binding gets directly to the Start property. So the notification works for single properties. But the tooltip binding is `{Binding Converter={StaticResource TooltipConverter}}` and does not bind to a specific property. When 'Start' changes, the bar is moved but the tooltip does not update because the tooltipconverter is not called again.

The bar is one object in an `ObservableCollection<Bar>`. Should the bar tell the collection or the view model? Normally is would not have any relationship to it.

Comment: raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` with `string.empty`

Comment: @Jehof That does not work.

Answer (score 7):

One possible workaround is:

Give your object a **ItSelf** property (or other name) like:

```
public Object ItSelf
{
    get { return this; }
}
```

Instead of binding

```
{Binding Converter={StaticResource TooltipConverter}}
```

use

```
{Binding ItSelf, Converter={StaticResource TooltipConverter}}
```

Then you raise `OnPropertyChanged` for ''ItSelf'' for every property. So you can signal an update for the whole object whenever it was used in a binding.

```
public DateTime Start
{
    get { return this.start; }
    set { this.start = value; OnPropertyChanged("Start"); OnPropertyChanged("ItSelf");
}
```

I got this to work a bit faster but would like to test out `AttachedBehavior` for this like stated by @AnatoliiG so I will accept an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the `INotifyPropertyChange` interface on a data type class, *that* takes care of notifying for changes to the class properties. If you implement the `INotifyPropertyChange` interface on a view model class that has a property of the type of your class, then *that* takes care of notifying for changes to that property, which in this case is the whole object.

---

UPDATE >>>

Right... I believe that you have a property of type `ObservableCollection<Bar>`. If you add a `PropertyChanged` handler to each of the items...:

```
foreach (Bar item in YourCollectionProperty) item.PropertyChanged += 
Item_PropertyChanged;
```

... then you can do this:

```
private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NotifyPropertyChanged("YourCollectionProperty");
}
```

Comment: I added some more details. Should the object when the property change notify the view model? Normally is does not know about the view model.

Comment: Does not this mean that he expects the whole collection to have changed and then redraw ALL bars and not only the one which in particular has changed?

Comment: This does not work. NotifyPropertyChanged does not redraw the bar. I guess he checks and finds the collection to be the same as before. But when in `Item_PropertyChanged` I do a `collection.Remove(sender)` and `collection.Add(sender)` it updates - because the bar is removed and re-added. Not sure if the best solution though. Still testing the others.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear:
You have some `DataTemplate` for item in a collection. Type of item is `Bar`. `ItemsSource` for parent list is a collection of `Bar` objects. You want to change tooltip if any property in particular `Bar` object changes.

Problem is that when you are not specifying specific path binding will subscribe to change notification of `DataContext` which in your case is `Bar`. So it does not care about changes or notifications within your object.
You can implement bubbling so changed event will be routed to parent object, but I would prefer defining separate `Changed` property for such kind of things.

```
public bool StateChanged
{
   get { return true; }
}
```

And subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event within your class:

```
this.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedHandler;
```

In handler notify that your object state changed:

```
private void PropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if  (!e.PropertyName.Equals("StateChanged"))
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged("StateChanged");
    }
}
```

Comment: But the binding does not bind to StateChanged and therefore does not update when `OnPropertyChanged("StateChanged")` is executed...

Comment: @ZoolWay Yes. You should bind to `StateChanged` and as a `ConverterParameter` pass `DataContext`. As simple as it is.

Comment: And how do I pass the current DataContext object as converter parameter? ConverterParameter is of type `object` and cannot use bindings.

Comment: @ZoolWay Yes, just forgot about that. So create `AttachedBehavior` instead of converter. Pretty straightforward thing.