# How to update binding to DataContext from within view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, ivalueconverter

I have a binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:Converter}}" />
```

with converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var vm = (ViewModel)value;
    return vm.SomeProperty;
}
```

Changing `SomeProperty` doesn't update the value on screen. Converter is not called.

How do I update such binding from within view model?

Note: in real project converter will be used to perform some calculation and returning result. In fact it will even be `MultiBinding` with similar bindings to different view models. I had problem with it and was able to narrow down the case to a simple `Binding`, where binding is not used to bind to a property, but like this.

---

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={local:Converter}}" />
    <Button Content="..." Click="Button_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

and code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ViewModel _vm = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _vm;
    }

    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => _vm.SomeProperty += "b";
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

    string _someProperty = "a";
    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set
        {
            _someProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeProperty));
        }
    }
}

public class Converter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var vm = (ViewModel)value;
        return vm.SomeProperty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a MultiBinding.

Comment: @Clemens, actually my problems started with `MultiBinding`, which didn't worked and then I narrow down the problem to normal binding.

Comment: As you can see from the answer, it isn't clear why you would do this at all, when you could as well directly bind to that property. You should add some explanation of the reasoning behind your approach.

Answer (score 0):

if the `ViewModel` is set to `DataContext` of the View. You can simply bind the Property by using `<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}" />`

From the comments, if you would bind the whole viewModel, because the converter do more stuff, than only convert type, or some thing. have a look at this: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19955529/8374986)

Comment: The whole point of story is not binding to a property. In real project converter will do some complicated stuff using different properties (even different view models) and returning result.

Comment: Then add more detailed information because your converter is only returing a property from the ViewModel. In the ViewModel the property is also a `string` so no converter is needed

Comment: a i see, then maybe this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19955529/8374986

Comment: *binding without path* - yes, this is duplicate of my question, thanks.